# Tableviewを移動して、また戻るとSwitchが初期化されてしまっている

Tags: swift

Swiftについての質問です。

Xcodeを開き`Creat a new project, single view app`で作成し、TableViewを２つ作りました。そして、２つのTableViewをつなぎ、片方にSwitchを付けました。コードは何も書いていません（初期状態のままです）。

写真の`Main.storyboard`の右側のTableViewでSwitchをoffにし、左のTableViewに移動。そして、また右のTableViewに戻ると、Switchがonの状態に戻っています。

Stepperで同様のことをしても戻ってしまいます。
原因がわかる方、ご回答をお願いします。

[image: Xcodeのスクリーンショット]

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

```swift
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIViewController.h>
#import <UIKit/UITableView.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKitDefines.h>

// Creates a table view with the correct dimensions and autoresizing, setting the datasource and delegate to self.
// In -viewWillAppear:, it reloads the table's data if it's empty. Otherwise, it deselects all rows (with or without animation) if clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear is YES.
// In -viewDidAppear:, it flashes the table's scroll indicators.
// Implements -setEditing:animated: to toggle the editing state of the table.

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE_IOS(2_0) @interface UITableViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (instancetype)initWithNibName:(nullable NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(nullable NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (nullable instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;

@property (nonatomic, strong, null_resettable) UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_2); // defaults to YES. If YES, any selection is cleared in viewWillAppear:

@property (nonatomic, strong, nullable) UIRefreshControl *refreshControl NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0) __TVOS_PROHIBITED;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

アドバイスありがとうございます。自分でなんとか頑張ってやってみます。最近始めたばかりなので、Swiftもこのサイトの使い方も無知で申し訳ないです。

Comment: 画像は必要な部分だけトリミング（=切り抜き）してから貼ってもらった方が見やすいと思います。貼られた画像は拡大も出来ないので文字が読めません。

Comment: あなたの現在のStoryboard設定だと、左画面→右画面の遷移は新しい画面を開くことになります。たとえ前の画面と同じデザインの画面が表示されても戻っているわけではありません。また右画面→左画面の遷移は「戻る」動作にならないといけないのに、そのような動作は行っておらず、新しい左画面を開いているだけの状態になっています。右画面のSwitchやStepperの状態を保存するにはある程度のコードを書かないといけないのですが、その前に直さないといけないことがいっぱいありすぎると言う状態です。少なくとも右画面・左画面それぞれに別々のViewControllerを割り当てるところくらいまでは自分でできないでしょうか？どなたか何もかも回答に書いてやろうと言う方が現れるかもしれませんが、もう少しご自分でできるところまではやっていただいた方が良いように思います。